# Prove the lower bound of an integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, logarithms, upper-lower-bounds

I am studying the following integral with parameter
$$E(t) = \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{1}{|\ln(T - s)|^2(t - s)}ds, \quad \text{for } t \in [-T/4, T].$$
$T$ is a constant that can be chosen arbitrarily small and $\lambda$ is defined as
$$\lambda(t) = \frac{T - t}{|\ln(T - t)|^2}.$$
We see that, at $t = T$,
$$E(T) = \frac{1}{|\ln(2T)|},$$
where we used the substitution $u = |\log(T - s)|$ in the integral to compute it explicitly. Now the thing is that for $t< T$ this function $E(t)$ is harder to manipulate as we cannot compute the integral anymore. I would like to prove that
$$E(t) - E(T) \ge 0$$
for every $t$ in $[-T/4, T]$. I computed $E(t) - E(T)$ using Python for $T = 0.04$ and it looks like on the picture below. The inequality seems obvious in this case.

[image]

I tried to see what was the shape of the derivative but $E'(t)$ is extremely ugly so I couldn't conclude anything from there. Moreover, I tried to rewrite $E(t) - E(T)$ as
$$E(t) - E(T) = \underbrace{\int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{1}{|\ln(T - s)|^2} \left(\frac{1}{t - s} - \frac{1}{T - s}\right)ds}_{\equiv A} - \underbrace{\int_{t - \lambda(t)^2}^T \frac{1}{|\log(T - s)|^2(T - s)}ds}_{\equiv B}$$
and then show that $A \ge B$ but again, it isn't obvious. Anyone has an idea about this ?

Comment: In your very first line, do you mean to have $|\ln(T-s)|$ in the denominator?

Comment: @CW279 OP uses that corrected integrand later in their post when they do $E(t)-E(T)$. I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: By saying that "$T$ can be chosen arbitrarily small", do you mean that you just want that inequality to hold for all $T\in(0,T_0)$ where one can choose $T_0>0$ to be whatever they want as the proof requires?

Comment: @fedja yes that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to figure it out from the other end. Namely, let's see for what positive functions $\varphi(\sigma)$ ($\sigma=T-t$) we have that
$$
F(\sigma)=\int_{\sigma+\varphi(\sigma)}^{2T}\frac{ds}{(s-\sigma)|\log s|^2}
$$
is increasing on $\sigma\in(0,\frac{5T}4)$. I'll assume that $T<\frac 1{2e}$, so all logarithms are negative and greater than $1$ in absolute value.

Taking the derivative in $\sigma$, we see that we need the inequality
$$
\frac{1+\varphi'}{\varphi |\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^2}
\le \int_{\sigma+\varphi}^{2T}\frac{ds}{(s-\sigma)^2|\log s|^2}
$$
We write the last integral as the sum of
$$
\int_{\sigma+\varphi}^{2T}\frac{ds}{(s-\sigma)^2|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^2}
=\frac{1}{|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^2}\left(\frac 1\varphi-\frac{1}{2T-\sigma}\right)
$$
and
$$
\int_{\sigma+\varphi}^{2T}\frac{ds}{(s-\sigma)^2}\left[
\frac 1{|\log s|^2}-\frac 1{|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^2}
\right]
\\
\ge 2\frac 1{|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^3}\int_{\sigma+\varphi}^{2T}\frac{ds}{(s-\sigma)^2}
\frac {(s-\sigma)-\varphi}{s}
$$
where we used the inequality
$$
|\log a|-|\log b|\ge \frac{b-a}b
$$
for $0<a<b<1$ and its consequence
$$
\frac 1{|\log b|^2}\ge
\frac 1{|\log a|^2}\frac 1{(1-\frac{(b-a)/b}{|\log a|})^2}
\ge \frac 1{|\log a|^2}\left(1+2\frac{(b-a)/b}{|\log a|}\right)\,.
$$
The last integral can be computed explicitly, but I'm not a big fan of partial fractions, so I'll just make the change of variable $s-\sigma=u$ and estimate it as
$$
\int_{\varphi}^{\infty}\frac{u-\varphi}{u^2(\sigma+u)}\,du-\int_{2T-\sigma}^\infty\frac{u-\varphi}{u^2(\sigma+u)}\,du=
\\
 \int_{\varphi}^{\infty}\frac{u}{u^2(\sigma+u)}\,du
-\int_{\varphi}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi}{u^2(\sigma+u)}\,du
-\int_{2T-\sigma}^{\infty}\frac{u-\varphi}{u^2(\sigma+u)}\,du
=I_1-I_2-I_3\,.
$$
Now  $I_1=\frac 1\sigma \log\frac{\sigma+\varphi}\varphi$,
$
I_2\le \frac 1\sigma
$
(ignore $u$ in $\sigma+u$)
and
$I_3\le \int_{2T-\sigma}^\infty \frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{1}{2T-\sigma}$.

Thus, bringing everything together and multiplying by $|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|^2$, we see that we will be happy if
$$
\frac{\varphi'}{\varphi}\le
-\frac{1}{2T-\sigma}\left(1+\frac{2}{|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|}\right)
+\frac{2}\sigma\frac 1{|\log(\sigma+\varphi)|}\left[\log\frac{\sigma+\varphi}\varphi -1\right]\,.
$$
Assuming that $\varphi\le e^{-1}(\sigma+\varphi)^2$ and recalling that all $|\log|$'s
are $\ge 1$ and $\sigma<\frac 54T$, we see that under these restrictions, we just need
$$
\frac{\varphi'}\varphi\le -\frac{4}T+\frac 2\sigma\,
$$
which calls for $\varphi(\sigma)=\sigma^2 e^{-1-\frac{4\sigma}T}$, which dominates $c(T-t)^2$ for $c=e^{-6}$, say, on the required interval. And you threw the whole $|\log\sigma|^4$ into the denominator of your $\lambda^2$, which was way more than really needed and which was the reason for such a sharp rise at the endpoint $t=T$ on your graph.

Technically you should also show that with my $\varphi$, one has $F(\sigma)\to F(0)$ as $\sigma\to 0$, but I leave that to you (hint: use the uniform equi-integrability criterion, not the DCT!)

The End.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this really complete answer and time spent on this question. Just I am not exactly sure how you get
$$\frac 1{|\log b|^2}-\frac 1{|\log a|^2}\ge
\frac 1{|\log a|^2}\frac 1{(1-\frac{(b-a)/b}{|\log a|})^2}
\ge \frac 1{|\log a|^2}\left(1+2\frac{(b-a)/b}{|\log a|}\right)\,.$$
I feel that we should rather have 
$$\frac 1{|\log b|^2}-\frac 1{|\log a|^2}\ge
\frac 1{|\log a|^2}(\frac 1{(1-\frac{(b-a)/b}{|\log a|})^2} - 1)\ge \frac 1{|\log a|^2}\left(2 \frac{b-a}{b|\log a|} - \frac{(b-a)^2}{b^2|\log a|^2}\right) \ge \frac 1{|\log a|^2}\frac{b-a}{b|\log a|}$$

Comment: It doesn't change anything for the rest of your argument, so thanks anyway!

Comment: @Falcon Yep, I forgot to subtract 1 on the RHS, (I edited) but otherwise the factor $2$ is crucial so you cannot afford to lose it. The inequality I used is $\frac 1{1-z}\ge 1+z$, which, when squared, gives what you wrote but with *plus*, not minus, in the parentheses!

Comment: @Falcon I though a bit about where your $-$ came from and, apparently, your logic was that $\frac 1{(1-z)^2}=\frac 1{1-(2z-z^2)}\ge 1+(2z-z^2)$, which is, of course, also correct, but way too weak, given that the LHS is actually $1+2z+3z^2+4z^3+\dots$

Comment: The $-$ came from 
$$\frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}- 1 = \frac{2 z - z^2}{(1 - z)^2} \ge 2 z - z^2.$$
But this is actually fine as you're just considering $1/|\ln b|^2$ and not $1/|\ln b|^2- 1/|\ln a|^2$, so there is no $-1$ in the expression above. I was just confused by the typo.

Comment: However, I am still struggling with the end of it: if we take $\varphi(\sigma) = \sigma^2/|\ln \sigma|^4=\lambda (\sigma)^2$ in the inequality you get 
$$\frac{\varphi '}{\varphi} = 2\frac{\lambda'(\sigma)}{\lambda(\sigma)}= 2\frac{|\ln \sigma|^2}{\sigma} \frac{|\ln \sigma| + 2}{|\ln \sigma|^3} = \frac{2}{\sigma} \left(1 + \frac{2}{|\ln \sigma|}\right)$$
which is bigger than 
$$-\frac{4}{T} + \frac{2}{\sigma}.$$
How do you conclude ?

Comment: @Falcon Nope! The whole idea is that you *do not* take your $\lambda^2$ for $\varphi$. You take my $\varphi(\sigma)=\sigma^2e^{-1-\frac{4\sigma}T}$ for which you do have monotonicity and notice that your $\lambda^2$ is *smaller* (when $T$ is small enough), so the integral corresponding to it is larger.

Comment: Ohh okayyy I got it, nice argument! Thank you.

Comment: But I guess that by changing a few things we should be able to prove that the inequality also holds for $\varphi = \lambda^2$ right ? By assuming 
$$\varphi \le \frac{(\varphi + \sigma)^2}{e|\ln(\sigma)|}$$
we get the inequality
$$\frac{\varphi'}{\varphi} = \frac{2}{\sigma}\left(1 + \frac{2}{\sigma}\right) \le -\frac{T}{4} + \frac{2}{\sigma}\left(1 + \frac{\ln|\ln \sigma|}{|\ln \sigma|}\right).$$
This is slightly better as we have a bigger coefficient in front of the $2/\sigma$, but this $-4/T$ is very annoying. Would you have an idea to get rid of it ?

Comment: @Falcon Inequality - yes (though it will become way more cumbersome). Monotonicity in the entire range - no. You, probably, noticed yourself that your graph goes up a bit near $t=-T/4$, so you just cannot get rid of $-4/T$ entirely and have to retract your initial gain a bit for large $\sigma$ to preserve the monotonicity in the entire range. Hence the (harmless) extra factor of $e^{-4\sigma/T}$ in $\varphi$. The whole ideas were a) to get a cheap monotonicity reason for the inequality and b) to get the largest (in the order of magnitude) offset you can really afford instead of $\lambda^2$.

Comment: Arrhh yes you are right. And if we assume $\sigma \in [0, T]$ instead ? Or $[0, 3T/4]$? We should be able to show that the function is increasing right ? I don't see how we could get rid of this negative $-4/T$ even if we consider a smaller interval.

Comment: The thing is that I would like to generalize this to a slightly different integral later on and if I can have that the function is increasing it would make my life way easier.

Comment: @Falcon I'm not sure what exactly is the problem you are trying to attract my attention to. Perhaps, you need to explain a bit more (or just post that "slightly different integral"). You have quite a large offset (my $\varphi$) for which the integral is monotone in $t$. You have your offset  (or just $c(T-t)^2$) which is monotone itself and still gives an even larger (but no longer monotone in $t$) integral. But you just *cannot* have a monotone offset for which the integral is monotone too: eventually one of the monotonicities should break down as $t$ goes to the left too far. Am I confused?

Comment: I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746476/bound-an-integral-depending-on-parameters) where I state more precisely what my problem is, feel free to take a glance if you are interested.

Comment: @Falcon Ah, OK, I see what you mean now. I'll think of it in the evening. Is that the final goal, or you will change the question again once it is figured out? :lol:

Comment: No no ahah this is indeed the final goal.