# Bound an integral depending on parameters

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let us define
$$E(t) = \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{ds}{|\ln(T - s)|^2(t - s)} \quad \text{and} \quad E^{\varepsilon}(t) = \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2 - \varepsilon}\frac{ds}{|\ln(T - s)|^2(t - s)},$$
for $t \in [-T/4, T]$, $\lambda(t)$ defined by
$$\lambda(t) = \frac{T - t}{|\ln(T - t)|^2},$$
and $0 < \varepsilon < T$ taken arbitrarily small (I aim to take $\varepsilon \to 0$ eventually). I aim to prove that, $\exists C > 0$ independent of $\varepsilon$ such that
$$|E^\varepsilon(t) - E^\varepsilon (T)| \le C|E(t) - E(T)|.$$
Using the answer given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744072/prove-the-lower-bound-of-an-integral-with-parameter/4744493?noredirect=1#comment10069759_4744493) we can show that we actually don't need that absolute values, so that I aim to prove
$$E^\varepsilon(t) - E^\varepsilon (T) \le C(E(t) - E(T)) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad  0 \le (CE(t) - E^\varepsilon(t)) - (CE(T) - E^\varepsilon(T)).$$
Now note that
$$E(T) = \frac{1}{|\ln(2T)|} \quad \text{and} \quad E^\varepsilon(T) = \frac{1}{|\ln(2T)|} - \frac{1}{|\log \varepsilon|},$$
which in the end leads to
$$0 \le (C - 1) \left(\int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{1}{|\ln(T -s)|^2(t - s)}ds - \frac{1}{|\ln(2T)|}\right) + \int_{t - \lambda(t)^2 - \varepsilon}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{1}{|\log(T -s)|^2(t - s)}ds - \frac{1}{|\log(\varepsilon)|}.$$
Basically, if I denote $G^C(t) = CE(t) - E^\varepsilon(t)$, I just want to show that $G^C(T) \le G^C(t)$ for every $t \in [-T/4, T]$. The annoying thing is that this $E(t)$ is hard to manipulate as we cannot explicitly compute the integral. I computed $G^C(t) - G^C(T)$ using Python for $T=4.10^{-5}$, $C = 4$ and $\varepsilon = T.10^{-5}$ (see picture below).

[image]

We see that the green curve is always "far" above zero in the interval we consider, so that the desired inequality seems reasonable (I did it for various other epsilon and the shape remain roughly the same).

However, I really struggle to prove it. I thought about computing the first derivative of $G^C(t)$ and show that it is decreasing in a certain range but the explicite form of the derivative is quite ugly so that I really struggle to prove the monotonicity. I also thought about showing that this function is concave, but this would involve computing the second derivative whose form is even worse to manipulate. Any idea to help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Some precision:**
It is actually fine if I can have an inequality of the type
$$|E^\varepsilon(t) - E^{\varepsilon}(T)| \le C\left(|E(t) - E(T)| + \frac{1}{|\ln(\varepsilon)|^2}\right),$$
so that I allow $|E^\varepsilon(t) - E^{\varepsilon}(T)|$ to be slightly bigger than $C|E(t) - E(T)|$ (with a difference of order $1/|\ln(\varepsilon)|^2$). I manage to show that
$$|E^\varepsilon(t) - E^{\varepsilon}(T)| \le C\frac{1}{|\ln(\varepsilon)|^2}$$
when $t \in [T - \varepsilon, T]$. If I could have
$$|E^\varepsilon(t) - E^{\varepsilon}(T)| \le C|E(t) - E(T)| $$
in the range $[-T/4, T-\varepsilon]$ I would be delighted. None of my attempt have been successful so far.

Comment: Just a stupid question: when $t<0$ and $\varepsilon\approx T$, so the upper limit in the integral defining $E^\varepsilon(t)$ is less than the lower one, is your $E^\varepsilon(t)$ just $0$? Or, perhaps, you'll be happy with the range $0<\varepsilon<T/2$ instead?

Comment: Yes yes, I would be happy with $\varepsilon < T/2$. In fact we can consider $\varepsilon$ as "negligible" compare to $T$.

Comment: It looks like (unless I've made a stupid error in my computations) your new inequality is just eventually false in the regime $\varepsilon=(T-t)^2, t\to T$ regardless of $T$ and $C$.  Try to check it numerically and if it agrees with what I said, I'll try to post the relevant estimates later.

Comment: Arrhh really? This is annoying. It is not obvious numerically to be honest, I tried to zoom on this region but I must admit that it is not that clear, Python doesn't give me a precise enough answer. The graph of $E^\varepsilon(t) - E^\varepsilon(T)$ seems to be "steeper" close to $T$ that's true, I guess that is the reason.

Comment: But anyway, thanks a lot for your time and your help! You can post the estimates as an answer when you've got time, I'll accept it.

Comment: @fedja Then do you think that it would be possible to prove such an inequality up to $(T - t)^2 = \varepsilon$?

Comment: "Up to" meaning "way above" or "way below"?

Comment: @fedja, I edited the question with some precision.